# How to deal with multi key values but reduce by the first key?

Tags: pyspark

if I have a key value pair like

```
('a',1),v1
('a',2),v2
('a',3),v3
('b',1),v4
('b',2),v5
('b',3),v6
```

How can i get

```
('a',1),v1
('a',2),v2+v1
('a',3),v3+v2+v1
('b',1),v4
('b',2),v5+v4
('b',3),v6+v4+v5
```

by using

```
flatmap().reducebykey()
```

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54226549/python-reduce-by-key-with-if-condition-statement/54228440#54228440) - you can do something similar.